# How to deal with "Open Till" hours in mysql when 04:00 > 23:00?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a query search for closing hours of stores.

The issue is that since some venues close at 2,3,4 am - how can I do a query of `where LESS THAN or EQUAL` when a table row value of 04:00 means more to me than 23:00?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a possibility of the closing time rolling over to another day? (e.g. a bar that's open from 4pm-2am)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point :)

Comment: Personally, i'd store the day (mon/tue/wed), opening time, then store how many hours they're open. So "Tue 16:00" & 10 hours would give you Tue 4pm - Wed 2am.

Comment: Wouldn't that be intensive for a query of hundreds of bars?

Comment: Well, what kinds of queries are you thinking about performing? Just simple dumps of all establishments within a parameter and then dump their hours of operations? Also, how many do you anticipate per page? And are hours of operations going to be a query parameter/filter?

Comment: I want to do queries of bla bla bla....Tuesday...WHERE Closing_Time equals/less-than 5am for example

Comment: something like [this perhaps](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0058a/1/0)?

Comment: Thanks, howver I made a mistake. I wanted to say equals or is more than..... In your example, no matter how high I set the query `ex:5am`, both rows are still shown.

Comment: So what's an example query you'd like to see given the link I provided? (or, better yet, populate more information in to that sqlfiddle and share that along with what you've tried and what you're going for)

Comment: Sorry brad, your execution was correct. It should be `less than` like you did. However, what I cannot understand is that when I set both Joe's and Kelly's bars to closed on Sunday and Monday, and set my code to look for Sunday and Monday - both tables still show up. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffeb8/1

Comment: you could do some research into Time stamps (like Suresh Kamrushi mentioned).

I have done something similar in the past, but using views to query the time between two different times. In the WHERE clause, try and implement something similar to this;

WHERE extract (hour from localtimestamp) between 4 and 23.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the closing time has to happen after the opening time, if `closing_time` is less than `opening_time` that means that the interval rolls over the next day.

How to check if a given time is inside an interval? A given time is inside an interval if:

- `given_time` is between `opening_time` and `closing_time`, when interval doesn't roll over;
- `given_time` is NOT between `opening_time` and `closing_time`, when closing time is on the next day.

As far as I remember, I think I've never used **XOR** in a SQL Query before, but here it fits perfectly:

```
closing_time<opening_time
XOR
  (time(now()) >= least(opening_time,closing_time) and
   time(now()) < greatest(opening_time, closing_time))
```

this gives true if `time(now())` is inside any interval, even if closing_time is less than opening_time. Notice that I had to use `>=` and `<`, using `>=` and `<=` (or its equivalent BETWEEN) won't always give the correct result, but I believe the logic is correct.

If we have to check if time(now()) is inside an interval of a specific dat, we still have a problem: if a store opens on Monday, and closes at 1AM, closing time is not on Monday anymore, so if we are past midnignt, and the interval is swapped, we have to check the interval of the previous day. This checks the correct opening_day:

```
opening_day =
date_format(now() - INTERVAL
    (closing_time<opening_time and time(now())<closing_time) DAY, '%a'))
```

if closing_time rolls on the next day, and current time is before closing time, the condition in () will be true so we have to check INTERVAL 1 DAY, otherwise condition is false and subtracting INTERVAL 0 DAY gives the current day.

So my final query is this:

```
set @n='2013-01-11 18:15:00';

SELECT
  e.name,
  hrs.opening_day,
  hrs.opening_time,
  hrs.closing_time
FROM
  hours_of_operation hrs join establishments e
  on hrs.establishment_id = e.id
     and not is_closed
     and ((hrs.opening_day=date_format(@n -
           INTERVAL
             (closing_time<opening_time and time(@n)<closing_time)
           DAY, '%a'))
          AND (closing_time<opening_time XOR
         (time(@n) >= least(opening_time,closing_time)
          and time(@n) < greatest(opening_time, closing_time))))
 ;
```

that gives all stores open at the given @n datetime. [Fiddle is here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9e18/46/1).

**EDIT:**

I had another (maybe weird?) idea to solve the same problem. It should be a little easier to understand. The first day of 2001 is `'2001-01-01'` which is a date that looks nice, and has also the interesting property of being a Monday. So my idea is to shift all dates (current date, opening date, closing date) back to this date.

Current date would then become:

```
'2001-01-01'
+ INTERVAL WEEKDAY( @n ) DAY
+ INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( @n ) SECOND
```

(we add the day of the week, weekday of a monday is 0 so we will still be on '2001-01-01', tuesday is 1 so it will be '2001-01-02' and so on). And using TIME_TO_SEC I'm adding the second to make a datetime field.

Opening date would be:

```
'2001-01-01'
+ INTERVAL
    FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')-1
  DAY
+ INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(opening_time) SECOND
```

to convert opening_day to the number of days to add I'm using [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function, then we have to subtract 1 since Monday starts to 1 here, and then we add the time part.

And the closing date would be:

```
'2001-01-01'
 + INTERVAL
     FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')
     -(closing_time>opening_time) DAY
 + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(closing_time) SECOND
```

same as opening date, but I'm subtracting 1 to DAY only opening_time is before closing_time, otherwise it means that closing_time happens on the next day. Then we only have to use BETWEEN to check if we are inside the interval, like this:

```
SELECT
  establishments.id,
  establishments.name,
  opening_time,
  closing_time
FROM
  `hours_of_operation` inner join establishments
  on hours_of_operation.establishment_id=establishments.id
     and not is_closed
     and
       '2001-01-01'
       + INTERVAL WEEKDAY( @n ) DAY
       + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC( @n ) SECOND

       BETWEEN

       '2001-01-01'
       + INTERVAL
           FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')-1
         DAY
       + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(opening_time) SECOND

       AND

      '2001-01-01'
      + INTERVAL
          FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')
          -(closing_time>opening_time) DAY
      + INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(closing_time) SECOND
```

[Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9e18/61/2).

But at this point, we can just **convert to seconds since the beginning of the week**, we have all elements to do this, and my final query would be this:

```
SELECT
  establishments.id,
  establishments.name,
  opening_time,
  closing_time
FROM
  `hours_of_operation` inner join establishments
  on hours_of_operation.establishment_id=establishments.id
     and not is_closed
     and
       WEEKDAY( @n ) * 86400 + TIME_TO_SEC( @n )    

       BETWEEN

       (FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')-1)*86400+
        TIME_TO_SEC(opening_time)

       AND

       (FIELD(opening_day,'Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun')
        -(closing_time>opening_time))*86400
        + TIME_TO_SEC(closing_time)
```

Comment: Thanks fthiella :) I tried to modify it a little bit, so I changed `set @n='2013-01-11 18:15:00';` to `$fullDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`. Then I proceeded to replace each `@n` with `$fullDate`, however that generated this error: `...server version for the right syntax to use near '02:32:56 - INTERVAL (closing_time...`. At that time, `$fullDate` was `2013-01-13 02:32:56`

Comment: At first I thought it was the space between the date and time, but the format is the same as you provided, so I really don't know.

Comment: @pufAmuf did you quote $fullDate with `'` ? its value should be `'2013-01-13 02:32:56'`, it might be this the problem, I think it should work

Comment: @pufAmuf pls see also my second query, it's a different approach :)

Comment: Thanks, the first example works great now :)! I will look at your second code in the morning, however it looks promising :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use datetime,timestamp or time as datatype. As it will be usefull in future for mathamatical calculations.

If you store it as string or number it will be difficult you to do something on it.

So be specific while choosing datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Pick an arbitrary date for storing opening and closing times, say Jan 1st 1900.

Any store that opens and closes on the same day uses this date for both times.

So a store that opens at 9am and closes at 5pm gets:

Open:  1900-01-01 09:00:00

Close: 1900-01-01 17:00:00

A store that opens one day and closes the next uses the following day for its closing time.

So a bar that opens at 4pm and closes at 2am the following day gets:

Open:  1900-01-01 16:00:00

Close: 1900-01-**02** 02:00:00

Now you can use greater than and less than queries and get the results you expect.

Comment: Thanks Dave, that was a really straightforward idea that I seriously considered for a moment, although it might pose some issues in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if `closing_time` is less than `opening_time` to know that this is meant to be the next day.

To get the valid opening time for a given datetime you also have to check if the given datetime is less than opening time to create the correct time interval.

To get the opening times for a given datetime use

```
SET @MyDate = Now();

SELECT 
  title,
  CAST( 
    CONCAT( 
      CASE 
        WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
          DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
        ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
      END, ' ', opening 
    ) AS DATETIME 
  ) open_from, 
  CASE 
    WHEN opening > closing THEN 
      CAST( 
        CONCAT( 
          CASE 
            WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
              DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
            ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
          END + INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' ', closing 
        ) AS DATETIME 
      )
    ELSE 
      CAST( 
        CONCAT( 
          CASE 
            WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
              DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
            ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
          END, ' ', closing 
        ) AS DATETIME 
      )
  END open_till
FROM 
  stores
ORDER BY
  open_from;
```

To get the actual `open`/`closed` state use

```
SET @MyDate = Now();

SELECT 
  title, 
  CASE
    WHEN 
      @MyDate >= CAST( CONCAT( CASE 
                           WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
                             DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                           ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
                         END, ' ', opening ) AS DATETIME )
    AND 
      @MyDate < CASE 
                WHEN opening > closing 
                THEN CAST( CONCAT( CASE 
                               WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
                                 DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                               ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
                             END + INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' ', closing ) AS DATETIME )
                ELSE CAST( CONCAT( CASE 
                               WHEN TIME( @MyDate ) < opening THEN 
                                 DATE( @MyDate ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                               ELSE DATE( @MyDate ) 
                             END, ' ', closing ) AS DATETIME )
              END
    THEN 'open'
    ELSE 'closed'
  END state
FROM 
  stores;
```

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31d60/5)

**UPDATE**

I have worked on your [SQL Fiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffeb8/1) and removed the obsolete column `closing_day`.

```
SET @MyTime = Now();

SELECT
  ho.`establishment_id`, e.`name`
FROM
  `hours_of_operation` ho
JOIN
  `establishments` e ON ho.`establishment_id` = e.`id`
WHERE
  NOT `is_closed`
AND
  `opening_day` = DATE_FORMAT( CASE 
                                 WHEN TIME( @MyTime ) < `opening_time` THEN 
                                   DATE( @MyTime ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                                 ELSE 
                                   DATE( @MyTime ) 
                               END, '%a' )
AND
  @MyTime >= CAST( CONCAT( CASE 
                             WHEN TIME(@MyTime) < ho.`opening_time` THEN 
                               DATE( @MyTime ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                             ELSE 
                               DATE( @MyTime ) 
                           END, ' ', ho.`opening_time` ) AS DATETIME )
AND
  @MyTime < CAST( CASE
                    WHEN ho.`opening_time` > ho.`closing_time` THEN
                      CONCAT( CASE 
                                WHEN TIME(@MyTime) < ho.`opening_time` THEN 
                                  DATE( @MyTime ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                                ELSE 
                                  DATE( @MyTime ) 
                              END + INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' ', ho.`closing_time` )
                    ELSE
                      CONCAT( CASE 
                                WHEN TIME(@MyTime) < ho.`opening_time` THEN
                                  DATE( @MyTime ) - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
                                ELSE 
                                  DATE( @MyTime ) 
                              END, ' ', ho.`closing_time` )
                  END AS DATETIME );
```

The solution is based on the same approach as posted above, but checks the opening hours per weekday.

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10959/10)

Comment: Wow thanks Sir Rufo! Sorry it's taking me so long to reply to your comments, I've been trying to disect everything and take my time with it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @pufAmuf yep, such queries let you know why formatting is your friend :o) you are welcome